# How to check if Google form was submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, google-forms

So, I have a client that wants to use Google Forms for a form on their website. They also want the user to be able to download some resources after successfully submitting the form. The problem is that the Google form has to be embedded with an iframe, so I can't find a way to check if the form has been submitted since it's happening within the iframe.

The mark up would be like this:

```
<div>
<iframe  
src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdtWuGTwEZEoqJAo0TXJt0LIMSO4g0Mot
YeVFUNY0slXBP4kQ/viewform?embedded=true" id="googleForm" width="760" height="500" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...
</iframe>
</div>
```

My question is: is there any way at all to check if the form was submitted, via jQuery, plain Javascript or anything else? Or, is there any script, or settings I can use within Google Forms to feed the user custom HTML after submitting the form?

Answer (score 1):

So the solution that I found came from this post: https://codepen.io/learningcode/post/customize-a-google-form-for-your-website

What you do is make your own form, and then add in the form actions from the Google Form (basically; I'm not positive on *how* it works but it does).

For example, the beggining of the form would look like this:

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/someotherlettersfromthegoogleform/formResponse">
   <label for="FNAME">First Name</label>
     <input name="entry.1499702011" type="text" id="FNAME" />
   <label for="LNAME">Last Name</label>
     <input name="entry.738838864" type="text" id="LNAME" />
</form>
```

Now, the Google Form is actually on the website, not embedded with an iframe, so I should be able to find a way to redirect the page or use a pop or something with the download links. I hope this answer can help out someone else who runs into this.

Comment: The bad thing about this workaround is that the form will not be updated, and if the form has many questions it could be really awkward to manage

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your client is trying to achieve but the only thing that comes to my mind is to use dedicated download links with landing page that triggers some action on your client website with AJAX. Well I know it's not the same as knowing whether client only submitted or submitted and downloaded the file but there's not much you can do anyway. Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Basically the client is set on using Google Forms to collect user information, and in exchange allow users to download a file. This would be simple to do with a regular HTML form, or any other form plugin, but it's not easy with google. See my answer for the closest solution I could find.